# Encapsulate (serialization) type class

Tags: haskell

I give an example to demonstrate my question.

Say I want to build a middle-level API for a key-value storage. The low-level API I base my API on consists of the following three basic functions:

```
put :: ByteString -> ByteString -> IO ()
get :: ByteString ->            -> IO (Maybe ByteString)
del :: ByteString ->            -> IO ()
```

with obvious semantics. To make my API more convenient, I want to pass not only `ByteString`'s but serializable objects. So in a first attempt I define

```
putOp :: Serialize a => ByteString -> a -> IO ()
getOp :: Serialize a => ByteString ->   -> IO (Maybe a)
```

this works although that `cereal` is hard-wired into my API feels odd. In fact, after some time I come across `binary-serialise-cbor` which looks promising. But changing from `cereal` to it would lead to a breaking change in my API.

#### Question

Is there a good way to "encapsulate" which serialization library I use internally (avoiding `UndecidableInstances`)?

Common sense might be writing an own class

```
class Storable a where
   encode :: a -> ByteString
   decode :: ByteString -> Either String a
```

and a newtype

```
newtype Encode a = Encode { unwrap :: a } deriving (Functor, Eq, Show)
```

and having it somewhat implicitly in `putOp` and `getOp`:

```
putOp :: Storable (Encode a) => ByteString -> a -> IO ()
putOp k x = put k (encode $ Encode x)

getOp :: Storable (Encode a) => ByteString -> IO (Maybe a)
getOp k = do
   x <- (get k) :: IO (Maybe (Encode a))
   return (unwrap <$> x)
```

where we have

```
instance Serialize a => Storable (Encode a) where
   encode = S.encode . unwrap
   decode (Encode r) = Encode <$> S.decode r
```

This looks ok; although

1. it adds overhead (or is it optimized away?) and
2. from the outside, the API now has the weird `Storable (Encode a)` context on its put/get and writing own instances for `Storable a` becomes writing instances for `Storable (Encode a)`.

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Uh, "interwiness"?

Comment: It's not clear to me that it's sensible to try to abstract away from this. In the end, if your user wants to use their own type, they're going to have to write an instance for whichever backend you end up choosing. It will just be an extra level of indirection for them to understand: "Oh, I need a `Storable (Encode MyFancyType)` instance, which means I need a `Serialize MyFancyType` instance... okay, I'll write a `Serialize MyFancyType` instance.". And now they're back to (having to) know which backend you chose.

Comment: @DanielWagner Ah, I see. So you would just keep the dependency of `cereal` and probably re-exporting the type class definition?